# Magento 2: Why is \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder Using Luma Theme And How to Change it?

Tags: magento2, transactional-mail

Why is the `transport builder` using Magento Luma as the theme for `emails`, (`logo`, `style`, etc) as opposed to `Magento Sales` / `Magento Checkout`? And how can this be changed?

Custom email:

```
    $transport = $this->_transportBuilder
        ->setTemplateIdentifier($code) // this code we have mentioned in the email_templates.xml
        ->setTemplateOptions([
            // this is using frontend area to get the template file
            'area' =>  \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
            'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
        ])
        ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $data])
        ->setFrom($sender)
        ->addTo($to)
        ->getTransport();

    $transport->sendMessage();
```

Comment: For which email ?

Comment: Custom email Edited question.

Comment: menu : Content > Design > Configuration > edit your store > Transactional Emails 
Logo come from here and Header Template in that header template added css file

Comment: It doesn't work